# Hide side bar after login

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I want a responsive page , when the login page is loaded it should hide the sidebar and should login page should span full page . After the user is login it should show the side bar with all the components. I tried few ways with the code below.

**app.component.html:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngIf="isLoggedUser == 'true'" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  isLoggedUser: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedUser = sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged');
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('isLogged') === 'true') {
      this.isLoggedUser = 'true';
    } else {
      this.isLoggedUser = 'false';
    }
  }
}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" (click)="login()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedUser: any;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'false');
  }

  login() {
    this.isLoggedUser = sessionStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true');
    this.router.navigate(['/users']);
  }
}
```

here I am trying to store a variable in session storage , before the user login the **isLoggedUser** flag will be false hence the sidebar will not be displayed . Once the user clicks the login the **isLoggedUser** will be made true , but the side bar is not displayed until I reload the page. Can someone please guide what is the bug/mistake in the code. And the page is not responsive for medium and small screens

StackBlitz (Demo) : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gtpz6w?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change the login method from **login.component.ts** to this one:

```
login() {
    this.isLoggedUser = 'true';
    sessionStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true');
    this.router.navigate(['/users']);
  }
```

Note: `sessionStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true');` doesn't return anything so `this.isLoggedUser` was getting set to `undefined`

I just replaced

```
this.isLoggedUser = sessionStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true');
```

with

```
this.isLoggedUser = 'true';
sessionStorage.setItem('isLogged', 'true');
```

Also need to have shared variable `isLoggedUser` so that when you update it in login component it's value will be refleted in app component also.

Comment: then how can I check the condition in app.component.ts for the sidebar ? @shivaji

Comment: Check how to share variable via service [here](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angular/sharing-data-between-angular-components-methods)